# Python lists manipulation

Tags: python, list

my question is why the first code is working but the second has error!?

**first code**

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange']
fruits += 'Banana'
```

**second code**

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange']
fruits = fruits + 'Banana'
```

can some one explain the reason because I know that :

```
num = 5
num = num + 1
```

is the same:

```
num += 1
```

Comment: Did you check the result? `fruits` -> `['Apple', 'Orange', 'B', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a']`

Comment: Consider: You're adding an integer to an integer, that's fine, they're the same type, but adding a string to a list is not the same.

Comment: You're adding apples and oranges... I mean, lists and strings. To add lists and lists, `fruits += ['Banana']`.

Comment: I am a beginner so I couldn't understand this but I just understand that variable += 1 is not exactly the same with variable = variable + 1

Comment: Your question is actually more advanced that you may have realised - you're right that, in some cases, those operations are not exactly the same. For some types, `__iadd__` allows some types that `__add__` may not - that question is actually already answered somewhere else, so I will close this question and link you there.

Comment: Note that, if you do `fruits += 'Banana'` it doesn't give you the result you may expect. Instead of adding `'Banana'` to the list, it adds `'B'`, `'a'`, etc. - not what you want. It does so because `__iadd__` allows you to add another iterable to a list, instead of just a list, and a string *is* an iterable of characters. You could do this `fruits += ['Banana']`, since this will add all elements of the second iterable to the first (just `'Banana'`) - which is what you want here, and the same would work with `fruits = fruits + ['Banana']`.

Comment: yes I know fruits += 'Banana' it doesn't give the result I may expect, I just confused when I saw the first code worked and the other not, thank you for your help